# Proving by Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics

Considering the case where the numbers 1 through 10 are in some order around a circle. Prove that some set of three consecutive numbers sums to at least 18.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integers $1, 2, \ldots, 10$ are circularly arranged in an arbitrary order.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142068/integers-1-2-ldots-10-are-circularly-arranged-in-an-arbitrary-order) I have given a solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142068/integers-1-2-ldots-10-are-circularly-arranged-in-an-arbitrary-order/142075#142075)